# update and delete table with foreign key data in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, join

I am just thinking of updating one table and deleting another table with foreign key of update table.

For example:

Table_1

```
studentId | name | exam
----------+------+---------
1         | abc  | physics
```

Table_2

```
examId | studentId | name 
-------+-----------+------
1      | 1         | ABC
```

now i am looking for a query where i update `table_1` with exam value 0 and delete the data from `table_2` with key `studentID` in one SQL query.

Comment: You cannot update and delete in the same query - consider using a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . And that is not even to mention the repetition of `studentid` and `name` in both tables.